# JavaScript - Sum of values in same rows and columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have JavaScript array with numbers 0 and 1 and I need to make a sum of all numbers in same row and column (if I imagine my array in two dimensions). I want to create second array with sums for every single value in first array.

2D array visualization for first item (X-Y table of values): 
**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**
**1**,1,1,1,1
**1**,1,1,1,1
**1**,1,1,1,1
**1**,1,1,1,1
(Sum: 8 for value at index 0;0 (with value itself excluded))

Real array I have: 
**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**,1,1,1,1,**1**,1,1,1,1,**1**,1,1,1,1,**1**,1,1,1,1
(Sum: 8 for value at index 0)

2D array visualization for second item: 
**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**
1,**1**,1,1,1
1,**1**,1,1,1
1,**1**,1,1,1
1,**1**,1,1,1
(Sum: 8  for value at index 1;0)
This way I need to loop through whole array.

2D array visualization for second item with zero separator: 
**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**
1,**1**,1,1,1
1,0,1,1,1
1,<strike>1</strike>,1,1,1
1,<strike>1</strike>,1,1,1
(Sum: 5  for value at index 1;0)
Values after zero I don't want to count in.

For previous table the result table should be like...
8,5,8,8,8
8,5,8,8,8
4,x,6,6,6
8,5,8,8,8
8,5,8,8,8

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question here is.  If the question is "is this possible", then yes, it definitely is.

Comment: This is going to look ugly and be difficult to read later when you need to maintain it.  I'd strongly recommend converting it into a multidimensional array first, and then simple loops can do the calculations for you.

Comment: Convert to multidimensional array first looks like the best approach.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but I don't know how...
I'am pretty confused with multidimensional arrays in JS. I used to work with them in C#, but in JS it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: OK, I have 2D array now.
`Array 0 [ 1, 1, 0, 1 ]`
`Array 1 [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ]`
`Array 2 [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ]`
`Array 3 [ 1, 1, 0, 1 ]`
But I can't figure out how to sum the value I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var res = [];  //the 1D array to hold the sums
var hArr =  [
   [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
   [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
   [ 1, 0, 0, 1 ],
   [ 1, 1, 0, 0 ]
]; //your array


var vArr = []; //Now lets create an array of arrays with the columns of hArr

for (var j=0; j<hArr[0].length; j++) {
  var temp = [];
  for (var i=0; i<hArr.length; i++) {
      temp.push(hArr[i][j]);
  }
  vArr.push(temp);
}

//sum all the element in the line - Vertically and Horizontally
function SumVH (hInd, vInd) {
  var sum = 0;
  //add horizontal elements
  //to the left
  for(var i=(vInd-1); i>=0; i--) {
    //if a 0 is found, break
    if (hArr[hInd][i] == 0) {
      break;
    }
    sum += hArr[hInd][i];
  }

  //to the right
  for(var i=(vInd+1); i<hArr[hInd].length; i++) {
    //if a 0 is found, break
    if (hArr[hInd][i] == 0) {
      break;
    }
    sum += hArr[hInd][i];
  }

  //add vertical elements
  //towards top
  for(var i=(hInd-1); i>=0; i--) {
    //if a 0 is found, break
    if(vArr[vInd][i] == 0) {
      break;
    }
    sum += vArr[vInd][i];
  }

  //towards bottom
  for(var i=(hInd+1); i<vArr[vInd].length; i++) {
    //if a 0 is found, break
    if(vArr[vInd][i] == 0) {
      break;
    }
    sum += vArr[vInd][i];
  }  
  //console.log("hInd="+hInd+" vInd="+vInd+" Sum="+sum);
  return sum;
}

// go through the main array and get result
var sumR = 0;
//sum of each row
for (var i=0; i<hArr.length; i++) {
   for (var j=0; j<hArr[i].length; j++) {    
      sumR = SumVH(i,j);
      res.push(sumR);
   }   
}
```

Please check it and let me know if it is working as you expect it to work.
`res` variable holds the result.

Comment: I have edited my answer to stop adding if a zero is encountered in the path. Please check and let me know if it satisfies your requirement. Thank you :) @Jan Chalupa

Comment: This is really going to be working great, but there is some problem. In most cases it gives mi values I expect but sometimes don't. `Array [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
Array [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ]
Array [ 1, 0, 1, 1 ]
Array [ 1, 1, 0, 1 ]`

`Array [ 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 1, 3, 1 ]` The second zero is wrong.

Comment: Found the bug and fixed it. I think it should not be giving you trouble anymore :) I have also updated it with your new test array from previous comment. And now the value of "res" is `[6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3]` Please check and confirm if it is working as expected. @JanChalupa

Comment: Unfortunately is it the same. In most cases it works, but for example this case: `[ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
[ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
[ 1, 0, 0, 1 ],
[ 1, 1, 0, 0 ]` it doesn't. It gives me result: `[ 6, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, **3**, 4, **3**, 4, 5 ]` I don't know why it sometimes work and sometimes don't. But I think that every error values are in the right bottom corner - is that usefull information? But in all cases your the king! :)

Comment: But according to what I understood, those '3's are correct (I just checked it with pen and paper :D). May be then I am getting something wrong here. because for the last **3**, sum will be from those 4 arrays,  [1, **1**, 1, 1], [1, **1**, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [**1**, 1, 0, 0] . Am I missing something here? @JanChalupa

Comment: Ok, tell me, will the sums be **2** and **1** respectively, for those 2 '3's ??? (If that is so, the misunderstanding is, I was always starting adding from left and top of that line.) Please confirm. @JanChalupa

Comment: I'm sorry but my English isn't the best one - now I'm little bit lost of what are you tellin' me. :D I'll try to describe it by an [image](http://www.imagehosting.cz/?v=beznzvcnc.png). First two horizontal lines are perfect (thank you for that), but the last two lines are wrong. Number should be red,red,3,2 for last but one line and red,0,red,1 for the last one. Red dots values doesn't matter to me. The dots should contain number of others blue dots near to them.

Comment: No no, it's fine, your English is fine. Look, my last solution gave a wrong array, which is `[ 6, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, **3**, 4, **3**, 4, 5 ]` for `[ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 1, 1, 0, 0 ]`. Now, all I am asking you is, give me the correct resulting array, so that I can compare with mine to find the bug. (Sorry, but the images totally went over my head :D)... Please just give me the correct values for the wrong ones and I will work it out :) @JanChalupa

Comment: Edited again. and this time answer is `[6, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3]`. Can you please test it once more? :P I hope this is final for both of us :P Can you please confirm @JanChalupa

Comment: After first test I can say "It works!". :) Thank you very much. I'm taking a note with your name and I'll mention you in credits (if I will finish this "master piece" sometimes). :D Do you have your own website (blog)?

Comment: My website (barick.in) is still a mess and so is blog. Everything is work in progress for now. Can we connect via **Facebook [https://www.facebook.com/liquidwhitelight]** till then? or may be **Linkedin [https://www.linkedin.com/in/sumanbarick]?** May I ask, what is it? a game I guess? :) But anyways, I wish you All The Very Best for whatever-you-are-trying-to-make here :) It was really challenging working on this and I enjoyed it. Thank you :) @JanChalupa

Comment: You can visit [honzachalupa.cz](http://www.honzachalupa.cz/) if you want to. :) When I will be within our work network, I will add you on Linkedin (it's blocked in our network :D ). Firstly it's a game and secondly it's little experiment. Is not the original game, it's a copy of existing game, but it's excuse to learn new things to me.

Comment: So kind of you for the _credit_ thing :) I can't thank you enough for that :) But for the time being selecting it as answer and upvoting will make me really very happy :D :D @JanChalupa