# JavaScript - Making a sum of values in same row and column

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I make a sum of values in same row and column and make another array (can be one-dimensional) of results.

```
Array [
    [ 1, 1, 0, 1 ],
    [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
    [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
    [ 1, 1, 0, 1 ]
]
```

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: Something like...`for (var iX = 0; iX < countInLine; iX++) {
  for (var iY = 0; iY < countInLine; iY++) {
   if($(this).hasClass("barrier") == false) {
    if (indexX == iX) {
     count++;
    }
    else if (indexY == iY) {
     count++;
    }
   }
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var res = [];  //the 1D array to hold the sums
var hArr =  [
   [ 1, 1, 0, 1 ],
   [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
   [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
   [ 1, 1, 0, 1 ]
]; //your array


var vArr = []; //Now lets create an array of arrays with the columns of hArr

for (var j=0; j<hArr[0].length; j++) {
  var temp = [];
  for (var i=0; i<hArr.length; i++) {
      temp.push(hArr[i][j]);
  }
  vArr.push(temp);
}

//sum all the element in the line - Vertically and Horizontally
function SumVH (hInd, vInd) {
  var sum = 0;
  //add horizontal elements
  for(var i=0; i<hArr[hInd].length; i++) {
    sum += hArr[hInd][i];
  }
  //add vertical elements
  for(var i=0; i<vArr[vInd].length; i++) {
    sum += vArr[vInd][i];
  }
  //console.log("hInd="+hInd+" vInd="+vInd+" Sum="+sum);
  return sum;
}

// go through the main array and get result
var sumR = 0;
//sum of each row
for (var i=0; i<hArr.length; i++) {
   for (var j=0; j<hArr[i].length; j++) {
      sumR = SumVH(i,j) - (2 * hArr[i][j]);
      res.push(sumR);
   }   
}
```

Please check it now. The variable `res` holds the result

> For my array writen above I want result array like 7, 7, 5, 7, 8, 8,
>   6, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 7, 7, 5, 7

Now the above code does not count the number itself in sum. But to get the result as your comment, please replace this line

```
sumR = SumVH(i,j) - (2 * hArr[i][j]);
```

with

```
sumR = SumVH(i,j);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much - I'm going to try that in the moment.

Comment: This doesn't work as I expect. For my array writen above I want result array like `7, 7, 5, 7, 8, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 7, 7, 5, 7` but I get `4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4`.

Comment: Please visit this page. It describes what I want better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294579/javascript-sum-of-values-in-same-rows-and-columns?noredirect=1#comment50579945_31294579

Comment: Ok, I got it. Doing it now.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check it now. It should work. @JanChalupa

Comment: Definitely this is the best solution I've had since now and I want to thank you for that! Now I need to exclude values behind the zero (as write in my previous link)...

Comment: You can thank me by choosing/voting up my answer if you like :)
And if you face any further difficulty with excluding the '0's issue, let me know by comments, I will code it once I get back from work. till then All the best :) @JanChalupa

Comment: I did. :) I don't know how to edit what you wrote to exclude the ones behind the zero like this...
**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**
1,**1**,1,1,1
1,0,1,1,1
1,_1_,1,1,1
1,_1_,1,1,1

Comment: Ok, I will edit my answer in your other link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294579/javascript-sum-of-values-in-same-rows-and-columns/31343893#31343893) of yours to solve this 0 thing :)

Comment: Done in the other link. Please check and comment there :) @JanChalupa